English character frequency calculation
I've written code to perform character frequency analysis on strings by taking the standard ETAOIN SRHD... frequencies of english character occurrence and I have two questions.

Is this the most optimal way to perform such an analysis.
If it isn't, what would be a more optimal method for performing the analysis?

This is the code I wrote:
englishLetterFreq = {
        'E' : 12.0,
        'T' : 9.10,
        'A' : 8.12,
        'O' : 7.68,
        'I' : 7.31,
        'N' : 6.95,
        'S' : 6.28,
        'R' : 6.02,
        'H' : 5.92,
        'D' : 4.32,
        'L' : 3.98,
        'U' : 2.88,
        'C' : 2.71,
        'M' : 2.61,
        'F' : 2.30,
        'Y' : 2.11,
        'W' : 2.09,
        'G' : 2.03,
        'P' : 1.82,
        'B' : 1.49,
        'V' : 1.11,
        'K' : 0.69,
        'X' : 0.17,
        'Q' : 0.11,
        'J' : 0.10,
        'Z' : 0.07
}

def calculate_frequency(msg):
        frequency = 0.0

        msg = msg.upper()

        for c in msg:
                if c in englishLetterFreq.keys():
                        frequency += englishLetterFreq[c]

        return frequency

If someone could take a look at my code and provide any insights I may be missing as a person with just introductory level cryptography skills, I would greatly appreciate it.
Thank you!

A frequency analysis does not seem to me to be the most promising approach for this short text (Leetspeak on top of that). Post the exact description of this challenge. On the web you can find this task in various challenges with the title Favourite Byte, but rather as an exercise on the topic of XOR and not on the topic of frequency analysis, e.g. https://trevorsaudi.com/posts/2023-03-01_crypto_basics/#challenge-favourite-byte.

However, as alluded to by Topaco, if you must use frequency analysis then you will have to modify the frequency table to reflect the 'Leetspeak' language which is not English after all, e.g. '3' has the frequency 'e' normally has in English, etc.

Both of you make valid points. I've since moved on as after further research, it appeared that frequency analysis wasn't the way to go for this challenge. Just raw brute-force to identify the key byte and the decrypted plaintext. I'll be rephrasing the question to only discuss the topic of frequency analysis without the connection to the challenge itself.
